# Es genau mit etwas nehmen

Tags: grammar, style

What is another alternative for the phrase "es genau mit etwas nehmen" ?

> Ich nehme es genau  mit dem Deutschlernen, wenn ich auf Germanstackexchange.com bin.

Comment: In order to provide an alternative, can you please explain a bit more in which context you want to use it? What do you want to express?

Comment: I wanna say it in this context : i want to be fluent in the german language and iam taking it seriously. :)

Comment: But what you say with that sentence is rather that you're picky or fussy with learning German.

Comment: Could you give us the exact English sentence? The context and the sentence you gave as an example do not quite match up meaningwise.

Comment: @sentryraven I want to say that i want to master german and it's dialects.

Comment: I replied to your question with an answer, which comes close to what you want to express.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wenn du es umdrehtest, würdest du sagen "Ich nehme es mit meinem Deutsch nicht so genau", das heißt es ist dir sozusagen egal, wenn du einige Fehler machst oder so. Meiner Meinung nach ist das eine bessere Benutzung des Begriffs "genaunehmen" bzw. "genaugenommen".

Du könntest auch sagen: "Ich führe meine deutschen Studien mit größter Sorgfalt aus, wenn ich auf Germanstackexchange.com bin"

Siehe: http://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/uebersetzung/mit+gr%F6%DFter+sorgfalt.html

Comment: Stimmt, das 'es' muss da sein. Der präzisen Wortstellung bin ich nicht sicher.

Comment: Gut, hab meinen Kommentar gelöscht, das verwirrt sonst

Answer (score 2):

> I want to say that i want to master german and it's dialects.

Taken from your comment on your original question, if you want to say the above, you'd rephrase it to:

> Ich möchte die deutsche Sprache und ihre Dialekte gewissenhaft erlernen/meistern.

I am lacking a good translation for *(to) master*, so if anybody else has a good idea, please let me know.

Comment: @SentryRavenCan I use "beherrschen" in this context as well?

Comment: Yes, it would also be a good translation for (to) master.

Comment: Ich möchte die deutsche Sprache u. ihre Dialekte beherrschen, denn danach werde ich eine weitere Sprache lernen.

Comment: Yes. That would be correct.

Comment: Danke sehr für die Hilfe!

Answer (score 1):

`auf Genauigkeit bei etwas achten`

> Ich achte auf Genauigkeit beim Deutschlernen, wenn ich auf `german.stackexchange.com` bin.

`pedantisch sein bei etwas`

> Ich bin pedantisch beim Deutschlernen, wenn …

Answer (score 1):

Wie wäre es mit folgender Formulierung?

> Ich lerne sorgfältig deutsch, wenn ich auf Germanstackexchange.com bin.

Substantiv: Sorgfalt

Adjektiv: sorgfältig